# Marginalisation on conditional probability

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I'm afraid this is an extremely simple question, but I didn't understand completely why if both $O_1$ and $O_2$ can be marginalised over $R$ the following holds:

$ P(O_2 = o_i |  O_1 = o_j) = \sum_r P(O_2 = o_i | R = r) P(R = r | O_1 = o_j)$

Thanks

Comment: Is this a [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question (they are handled differently)? Please add the self-study tag if appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure about the first term on the right hand-side of your expression?

Comment: Have you worked it out? Would you consider to write your solution as en edit/addition to your question or an answer (for the benefit of others)?

Comment: @QuantIbex I think I have, I'm quite busy atm, but will edit the question asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems to by a [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question. For the moment I'll provide hints that will hopefully lead to the correct expression.

Assuming that $P(O_1  = o_j) > 0$ and by the definition of [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition) 
$$
P(O_2 = o_i \mid O_1 = o_j) = \frac{P(O_2 = o_i , O_1 = o_j)}{P(O_1 = o_j)} .
$$
Moreover, by the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)
$$
P(O_2 = o_i, O_1 = o_j) = \sum_r P(O_2 = o_i, O_1 = o_j, R = r) .
$$
Combining these two expressions and further applications of both the definition of conditional probability as well as the loaw of total probability should lead to the correct expression.